# Rest API in self-hosted page doesn't work

Tags: rest-api, wordpress.com-hosting

First of all, I'm a total WordPress newbie and I genuinely couldn't find an answer to my question:

I have a site hosted in WordPress (https://srebelo80.wordpress.com) which I'm planning to use as a testing API endpoint, however, when I test the endpoint `https://srebelo80.wordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` I get a `Page not found`.

I'm reading the documentation and it seems like WordPress has integrated Rest API to the core so in technically this *should* work without any plug-ins?

Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: wordpress.com is not self-hosted. "Self-hosted" refers to sites that are _not_ on WordPress.com. The API works differently on WordPress.com. https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Comment: Yes, I'm editing that part. I meant hosted on WP :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're not using self-hosted WP, since you clearly mentioned that your site is running on wordpress.com...

And if it really is hosted on WordPress.com, then you'll have to use REST API a little bit different.

Your API is available here:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/srebelo80.wordpress.com
```

Here you can find Console - you can use it for easy testing: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant public hosted :) Cool, this is all I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!